# Cómo cargar estilos CSS dinámicamente? Tiene un bug Angular?

Tags: css, angular

Mi proyecto tiene un pequeño sistema de temas, es decir, yo clickeo un botón de color azul y mi sistema carga dinámicamente el css que le da los nuevos estilos y colores de entorno azul a mi proyecto, y lo mismo con 6 colores diferentes. Al comienzo me aparecía un error de MIME/type cuando trataba de cargar el css desde el typescript y lo solucione utilizando el `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` de angular.

Creí que era todo pero me di cuenta de que había cierto "parpadeo", como que un botón es de color celeste y el tema por defecto es azul, entonces como que el botón pierde el azul, se pone celeste y tras medio segundo se vuelve a poner azul.

Es como si perdiera conexión con el CSS linkeado, entonces entre a la consola del navegador y en el apartado de NETWORK me di cuenta de que salía status 304 al archivo linkeado (del color azul). Leí en internet que eso te dice que el archivo requerido ya se encuentra en caché.

Luego de probar y probar cosas me di cuenta de que dicho "parpadeo" solo pasa cuando se ejecuta alguna consulta al backend. Por ejemplo, tengo una función que cuenta los usuarios online cada 5 segundos, así que cada 5 segundos se nota el "parpadeo" y no tengo ni idea de como hacer que NO parpadee o no pierda la hoja de estilos. Estoy muy estresada porque no se ni que intentar ya que no entiendo del todo el problema. Espero haberles explicado bien lo que pasa.
Les agradecería muchísimo si pudieran ayudarme al menos a entender o tener una pista de que hacer!

Les dejo el código de como linkeo los css en caso de que lo necesiten ver:

En la primera línea de mi page.component.html

```
    <link id="temaTeed" rel="stylesheet" [href]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(cssUrl)">
```

En el page.component.ts

```
    export class PageComponent {
      cssUrl = '../../../assets/colors/color_4.css';
      temaLocal = localStorage.getItem('tema');
    
      constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { 
        this.evaluarCssTema(this.temaLocal); 
      } 
    
      evaluarCssTema(tema){
        if(tema){
          this.cssUrl = '../../../assets/colors/'+tema+'.css';
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Procura evitar las mayúsculas sostenidas, que se asimilan a gritos y pues, claramente no es la idea. :)

Comment: Podrías compartir mas código? para poder ayudarte